# Remove text outside xml tags - PHP

Tags: php, xml, error-handling

Some times I receive text outside the xml tags in XML like this:

```
Bad command error. XYZ. Some more text<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml></xml>
```

This returns error in php. Because I am using this function to read the xml:

```
simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

Is there a way that I can remove the text outside xml tags so that i do not get error in xml ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't specify where the XML is coming from. If it's another part of your system, then it sounds like you need to fix a bug there, rather than working around it when you get the broken XML. If it's coming from a third party, then you should notify them that they have a bug in their system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/<\\?xml.*\\?>.*/", $xml, $matches)) {
    $xml = $matches[0];
}
```

Comment: Then some more description is needed as this works fine:

    <?php 
    $xml = 'Bad command error. XYZ. Some more text<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml></xml>';
    if (preg_match("/<\\?xml.*\\?>.*/", $xml, $matches)) {
 $xml = $matches[0];
    }
    simplexml_load_string($xml);

Comment: I just copy pasted what you gave me and it returns this error: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, which will extract xml only.

```
$lpos = strpos('<?xml', $xml);
$xml = substr($xml, $lpos, strrpos('>', $xml) - $lpos +  1);
```

But it has some limitations, for example: there can be '>' char after the xml.
Also i'd recommend to try [`tidy_repair_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php)

Answer (score 0):

Quick one-liner.

```
$xml = preg_replace("/^.+<\\?xml/", "<?xml", $xml, 1);
```

Will strip off any characters found in the string prior to the `<?xml` marker.

However, I would say that if you're getting badly formatted XML like this, you should be trying to track down the reason for the bad formatting rather than just trying to work around it.

It sounds like there's a nasty bug in the code that generates the XML in the first place. If it's your code, you need to be fixing the problem there, rather than dodging the issue. If it's coming from a third party system, you need to notify them of the bug.